C# X509Chain.Build() failing to verify certificate with RevocationStatusUnknown error
I'm using Windows 11, i created a selft signed certificate in pfx format with appropriate keyUsage, basicConstraints and SubjectKeyIdentifier in order to make a CA Certificate. I added this certificate to trusted CA list using certmgr. I made a client certificate from this CA certificate in order to test my own ocsp server coded in c#. Client certificatehas AIA Extension for OCSP pointing on URL:
http://localhost:8080/ocsp/

In order to sign OCSP requests, i created a designated certificate with ocspSigning extension. OCSP Server seems to work fine, it can received and send response. I tested some responses of the server using Bouncycastle and everything seems to be fine but when i use X509Chain.Build() it fails to build the chain:
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2("client.pfx", "password");
X509Chain ch = new X509Chain();
X509ChainPolicy pol = new X509ChainPolicy();
pol.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
ch.ChainPolicy = pol;
ch.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;
Console.WriteLine(ch.Build(certificate));
Console.WriteLine("Chain Information");
Console.WriteLine("Chain revocation flag: {0}", ch.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag);
Console.WriteLine("Chain revocation mode: {0}", ch.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode);
Console.WriteLine("Chain verification flag: {0}", ch.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags);
Console.WriteLine("Chain verification time: {0}", ch.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime);
Console.WriteLine("Chain status length: {0}", ch.ChainStatus.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Chain application policy count: {0}", ch.ChainPolicy.ApplicationPolicy.Count);
Console.WriteLine("Chain certificate policy count: {0} {1}", ch.ChainPolicy.CertificatePolicy.Count, Environment.NewLine);

//Output chain element information.
Console.WriteLine("Chain Element Information");
Console.WriteLine("Number of chain elements: {0}", ch.ChainElements.Count);
Console.WriteLine("Chain elements synchronized? {0} {1}", ch.ChainElements.IsSynchronized, Environment.NewLine);

foreach (X509ChainElement element in ch.ChainElements)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Element issuer name: {0}", element.Certificate.Issuer);
    Console.WriteLine("Element subject name: {0}", element.Certificate.Subject);
    Console.WriteLine("Element certificate valid until: {0}", element.Certificate.NotAfter);
    Console.WriteLine("Element certificate is valid: {0}", element.Certificate.Verify());
    Console.WriteLine("Element error status length: {0}", element.ChainElementStatus.Length);
    foreach(var crs in element.ChainElementStatus)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(crs.Status);
        Console.WriteLine(crs.StatusInformation);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Element information: {0}", element.Information);
    Console.WriteLine("Number of element extensions: {0}{1}", element.Certificate.Extensions.Count, Environment.NewLine);

    if (ch.ChainStatus.Length > 1)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < element.ChainElementStatus.Length; index++)
        {
                Console.WriteLine(element.ChainElementStatus[index].Status);
        Console.WriteLine(element.ChainElementStatus[index].StatusInformation);
    }
}

Result:
Chain Information
Chain revocation flag: EntireChain
Chain revocation mode: Online
Chain verification flag: NoFlag
Chain verification time: 08/10/2024 07:25:52
Chain status length: 1
Chain application policy count: 0
Chain certificate policy count: 0

Chain Element Information
Number of chain elements: 2
Chain elements synchronized? False

Element issuer name: C=FR, S=Nouvelle-Aquitaine, L=Limoges, O=Universal Administration, CN=Universal Administration
Element subject name: C=FR, S=Nouvelle-Aquitaine, L=Limoges, O=Universal Administration, OU=Universal Administration Video Converting Client 1, CN=Universal Administration Dataclient
Element certificate valid until: 07/10/2029 22:43:08
Element certificate is valid: False
Element error status length: 1
RevocationStatusUnknown
Element information:
Number of element extensions: 1

Element issuer name: C=FR, S=Nouvelle-Aquitaine, L=Limoges, O=Universal Administration, CN=Universal Administration
Element issuer name: C=FR, S=Nouvelle-Aquitaine, L=Limoges, O=Universal Administration, CN=Universal Administration
Element certificate valid until: 07/10/2124 14:28:15
Element certificate is valid: True
Element error status length: 0
Element information:
Number of element extensions: 4

False

I can't figure out why X509Chain.Build() fails to check revocation status and some help would be appreciated
Here is the base64 encoded response of my ocsp server:
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

You can check it using online ASN.1 Javascript Decoder for example
Here the code i used to create my CA Cert:

static void CreateBaseCertificate()
{
    using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048))
    {
        var request = new CertificateRequest("C=FR, ST=Nouvelle-Aquitaine, L=Limoges, O=Universal Administration, CN=Universal Administration", rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(true, false, 0, false));
        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(request.PublicKey, false));
        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.KeyCertSign, false));
        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(CreateOcspAiaExtension("http://localhost:8080/ocsp/"));

        X509Certificate2 certificate = request.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(100));

        var pfxPath = @"ca.pfx";
        File.WriteAllBytes(pfxPath, certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "password"));

        File.WriteAllText("ca.key", rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKeyPem());

        Console.WriteLine($"Certificat X.509 généré et sauvegardé en tant que PFX à : {pfxPath}");
    }
}

Here is the code to create client certificate:
static void CreateDataclientCertificate(string countrycode, string state, string city, string unit)
{
    X509Certificate2 cacert = new X509Certificate2("ca.pfx", "password");
    using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048))
    {
        var request = new CertificateRequest("C=" + countrycode + ", ST=" + state + ", L=" + city + ", O=Universal Administration, OU=" + unit + ", CN=Universal Administration Dataclient", rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(CreateOcspAiaExtension("http://localhost:8080/ocsp/"));
        
        X509Certificate2 certificate = request.Create(cacert, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(5), new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 });
        certificate = certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa);
        var pfxPath = @"client.pfx";
        File.WriteAllBytes(pfxPath, certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "password"));

        Console.WriteLine($"X509 Certificate generated and saved as pfx at : {pfxPath}");
    }
}

Here is the code for the OCSP Signing certificate:
static void CreateOCSPCertificate(string countrycode, string state, string city, string unit)
{
    X509Certificate2 cacert = new X509Certificate2("ca.pfx", "password");
    using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create(2048))
    {
        var request = new CertificateRequest("C=" + countrycode + ", ST=" + state + ", L=" + city + ", O=Universal Administration, OU=" + unit + ", CN=OCSP signing certificate", rsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);

        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509BasicConstraintsExtension(false, false, 0, true));
        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509SubjectKeyIdentifierExtension(request.PublicKey, false));
        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(
            new X509KeyUsageExtension(X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature, true));
        Oid ocspSigningOid = new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.9");
        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(new X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension(
            new OidCollection { ocspSigningOid }, true));

        request.CertificateExtensions.Add(CreateOcspAiaExtension("http://localhost:8080/ocsp/"));

        X509Certificate2 certificate = request.Create(cacert, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(-1), DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(5), new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0 });
        certificate = certificate.CopyWithPrivateKey(rsa);
        var pfxPath = @"ocsp.pfx";
        File.WriteAllBytes(pfxPath, certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "password"));
        File.WriteAllText("ocsp.key", rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKeyPem());
        Console.WriteLine($"X509 Certificate generated and saved as pfx at: {pfxPath}");
    }
}

static System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Extension CreateOcspAiaExtension(string ocspUrl)
{
    Oid ocspOid = new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1");

    AsnWriter writer = new AsnWriter(AsnEncodingRules.DER);

    writer.PushSequence();

    writer.PushSequence();

    writer.WriteObjectIdentifier(ocspOid.Value, Asn1Tag.ObjectIdentifier);

    var uriTag = new Asn1Tag(TagClass.ContextSpecific, 6);
    using(writer.PushSequence(uriTag))
        writer.WriteCharacterString(UniversalTagNumber.IA5String, ocspUrl);

    writer.PopSequence();

    writer.PopSequence();

    return new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Extension(new Oid("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1"), writer.Encode(), false);
}


Why are you messing around with creating the AIA yourself, why not just use new X509AuthorityInformationAccessExtension([ ocspUrl ], [])? Also you seem to be missing the OCSP No Revocation Checking OID 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1.5

I'm referring to the OCSP Responder certificate in the above. It needs No Revocation as a non-critical extension, otherwise anyone verifying signed OCSP responses would need to use OCSP recursively to verify itself, which is impossible. Also OCSP certs should have very short lifetimes, like 2 weeks or a month.

Thank you very much, No Revocation Checking extension has been added to OCSP Responder certificate. I dont use new X509AuthorityInformationAccessExtension([ ocspUrl ], []) because X509Chain.Build throws an OfflineServerException

I'll be honest i don't think the OCSP cert should have an AIA extension anyway, it's not on the OCSP certs that I've checked, and logically seems unnecessary.

Indeed, i just added it for test purpose

OfflineServerException is a good start: it sounds like the OCSP server isn't actually online from its point of view, does this client have line of sight with the OCSP server? Try test the end certificate with certutil -f -urlfetch -verify CertificateFile.cer see eg https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/basic-crl-checking-with-certutil/ba-p/1128367 it should give you more verbose logging on what exactly is going wrong.

Out of curiosity why are you trying to reimplement a CA and OCSP responder when perfectly good prebuilt alternatives exist, such as Windows Server CA or FreeIPA?

certutil -verify client.pem throws a 0x800b010a (-2146762486 CERT_E_CHAINING) error. That's weird.... the CA is in CA store....
But certutil -verify client.pem ca.pem throws an 0x80093102 (ASN: 258 CRYPT_E_ASN1_EOD) error for CA cert.
I want to make my own OCSP Responder and CRL because there is none in c# and i'd like to be able to customise server processing and responses

My badd, i added the CA cert to local machine CA cert list and now this is i get 0x80092012 (-2146885614 CRYPT_E_NO_REVOCATION_CHECK) Revocation check ignored -- no information about revocation available. Yet, the certificate has AIA extension

When i check my OCSP server, it doesn't receive anything ith certutil. I tried to recreate client certificate using new X509AuthorityInformationAccessExtension(["http://localhost:8080/ocsp/"], null, true) and certutil says server is offline but when i check my OCSP server, it receives 2 requests.

Then it's probably some issue with the OCSP response, but we haven't seen any of that code. Looking at your response, I decode the Base64, then re-decoded the inner Response. We have a BasicOCSPResponse, but the SingleResponse appears incorrect. RFC6960 specifies a Sequence of certID, certStatus, thisUpdate, and optionally nextUpdate and singleExtensions. You don't have that you've got some mess of nested Sequences. Then the signatureAlgorithm is a Sequence when it should be a bare OID. I haven't checked the signature, but it needs to be sha256WithRSAEncryption hash of the Response.

Problem solved. The issue was coming from the way OCSP signing certificate ASN.1 data wass written in OCSP response. I corrected it and now X509Chain is building the chain and checking revocation properly.
